# Splitting bracket-separated string to a dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I want to make this string to be dictionary.

```
s = 'SEQ(A=1%B=2)OPS(CC=0%G=2)T1(R=N)T2(R=Y)'
```

Following

```
{'SEQ':'A=1%B=2', 'OPS':'CC=0%G=2', 'T1':'R=N', 'T2':'R=Y'}
```

I tried this code

```
d = dict(item.split('(') for item in s.split(')'))
```

But an error occurred

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #4 has length 1; 2 is required
```

I know why this error occurred, the solution is deleting bracket of end

```
s = 'SEQ(A=1%B=2)OPS(CC=0%G=2)T1(R=N)T2(R=Y'
```

But it is not good for me. Any other good solution to make this string to be dictionary type ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `if` condition in your generator expression.

```
>>> s = 'SEQ(A=1%B=2)OPS(CC=0%G=2)T1(R=N)T2(R=Y)'
>>> s.split(')')
['SEQ(A=1%B=2', 'OPS(CC=0%G=2', 'T1(R=N', 'T2(R=Y', '']
>>> d = dict(item.split('(') for item in s.split(')') if item!='')
>>> d
{'T1': 'R=N', 'OPS': 'CC=0%G=2', 'T2': 'R=Y', 'SEQ': 'A=1%B=2'}
```

Comment: I'd also recommend saying `if item` instead of `if item !=''` since '' is an empty string anyway.

Answer (score 5):

More compactly:

```
import re

s = 'SEQ(A=1%B=2)OPS(CC=0%G=2)T1(R=N)T2(R=Y)'
print dict(re.findall(r'(.+?)\((.*?)\)', s))
```

Comment: Perfect solution, more compact and simple approach.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, this could be solved with a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'SEQ(A=1%B=2)OPS(CC=0%G=2)T1(R=N)T2(R=Y)'
>>> print dict(match.groups() for match in re.finditer('([^(]+)\(([^)]+)\)', s))
{'T1': 'R=N', 'T2': 'R=Y', 'SEQ': 'A=1%B=2', 'OPS': 'CC=0%G=2'}
```